# Android Material Button Toggle Group

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-button, material-components-android

I'm creating a form in android which asks for gender. To get this input I use Material Button Toggle Group which contains two buttons. I don't know how to know which button is clicked in my activity.java. How to get to know about the selected button in my activity so that i can save the details in different database.

**myxml.xml**

```
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
                android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:singleSelection="true">
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Male"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"/>
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Female"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"/>

            </com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>
```

**Myactivity.java**

```
    MaterialButtonToggleGroup toggleButton = findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
    toggleButton.addOnButtonCheckedListener(); 
    // I CAN'T FIND ANY PROPER SOLUTION
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the **`getCheckedButtonId()`** method.
Something like:

```
MaterialButtonToggleGroup materialButtonToggleGroup = 
         findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
int buttonId = materialButtonToggleGroup.getCheckedButtonId();
MaterialButton button = materialButtonToggleGroup.findViewById(buttonId);
```

---

Only if you need a listener you can use the `addOnButtonCheckedListener`:

```
materialButtonToggleGroup.addOnButtonCheckedListener(new MaterialButtonToggleGroup.OnButtonCheckedListener() {
      @Override
      public void onButtonChecked(MaterialButtonToggleGroup group, int checkedId, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
          if (checkedId == R.id.button1) {
            //..
          }
        }
  }
});
```

You have to check the `checkedId` value but also the `isChecked` value. The same listener is called when you check a button but also when you unckeck a button.

It means that if you click the `button1` the listener is called with `isChecked=true` and `checkedId=1`. Then if you click the `button2` the listener is called twice. Once with `isChecked=false` and `checkedId=1`, once with `isChecked=true` and `checkedId=2`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this :

```
toggleButton.addOnButtonCheckedListener(new MaterialButtonToggleGroup.OnButtonCheckedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onButtonChecked(MaterialButtonToggleGroup group, int checkedId, boolean isChecked) {
                if(group.getCheckedButtonId()==R.id.button1)
                {
                    //Place code related to button1 here
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity2.this, "Button1 Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }else if(group.getCheckedButtonId()==R.id.button2) {
                    //Place code related to button 2 here
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity2.this, "Button2 Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Concise Kotlin version of Gabriele's answer in case anyone is looking for one:

```
findViewById<MaterialButtonToggleGroup>(R.id.toggle_group).apply {
    addOnButtonCheckedListener { group, checkedId, isChecked ->
        if (!isChecked) return@addOnButtonCheckedListener
        when(checkedId){
            R.id.button1 -> //..
            R.id.button2 -> //..
        }
    }
}
```