# can i hide button untill the user click on another button in android java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
  public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.true_button:
            checkAnswer(true);
            break;

        case R.id.false_button:
            checkAnswer(false);
            break;

        case R.id.image_next:
            currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % questions.length;
            updateQuestion();
            break;

        case R.id.image_back:
            if (currentIndex > 0){
                currentIndex = (currentIndex - 1) % questions.length;
                updateQuestion();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"No Back Qouestions....",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

    }
}

private void updateQuestion() {
    textView.setText(questions[currentIndex].getText());
}

private void checkAnswer(boolean userchoosen) {
    boolean answerIsTrue = questions[currentIndex].isAnswer();
    int toastMessageId = 0;

    if (userchoosen == answerIsTrue) {
        toastMessageId = R.string.correct_answer;
        if (userchoosen == true){
        trueButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else{
            falseButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    } else {
        toastMessageId = R.string.wrong_answer;
    }
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, toastMessageId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}}
```

Now i need when i click on true button and the right answer is true the false button be hidden untill the user click back or forward , i'm trying to add visibility is visible in back and forward button but it not working well , and i need if any notes of my code ,thank you alot..

Comment: I think is possible, but I'm going to suggest that you use `setEnabled(false)` instead.  This will grey the button out and make it obvious to the user that the button cannot be used, while at the same time being a lot easier on you to implement.  Actually removing a button is more difficult, and will jank around the UI layout, and actually making it invisible might be rather difficult.

Comment: thank for your time , i will try this but i will explain to you more , i don't absolutely want to cancel it i need to invisible it untell the user click forward or back button , @markspace

Comment: use MaterialButtonToggleGroup look at here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62346373/android-material-button-toggle-group

Comment: What do you mean by "not working well"? As of now, it seems like both "trueButton" and "falseButton" are visible in the beginning, and the corresponding button gets invisible if the user got the correct answer. You also mentioned "until the user click forward or back button"; in this case, you want to set both "trueButton" and "falseButton" to visible. In addition, it seems like you want to make the "falseButton" invisible when "userchoosen" is true and vice versa instead of the other way around as you have right now.