# Android Studio Button Onclick From Separate Function

Tags: java, android

hi i have a question about my android app

I want to make a game that will basically show the user a certain object, and two buttons that will respectively accept or decline said object.

How do I make it so that the central code can read the buttons input in the middle of execution?

Essentially, I want to be able to read if the user has clicked a button from the middle of a different function.

Please let me know how i can improve my question.

Comment: If you want to give an indication in the UI of which option the user selected, look into a [Material Button Toggle Group](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButtonToggleGroup) - it makes a group of buttons [only one of which can be selected](https://www.journaldev.com/31950/android-materialbuttontogglegroup), which will be a lot more clear to a user than a pair of regular buttons. When you want to see which one is selected somewhere else, [you can get the state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62346373/android-material-button-toggle-group)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully I am getting this right (your question is hard to understand).

So, what you want is to gauge whether or not a user has clicked on a certain button in the middle of another method?

If so, you could implement something *similar* to the following:

```
var buttonAClicked = false
var buttonBClicked = false

binding.buttonA.setOnClickListener {
    buttonAClicked = true
}

binding.buttonB.setOnClickListener {
    buttonBClicked = true
}

binding.nextButton.setOnClickListener {
    // reset both variables here after new object
    buttonAClicked = false
    buttonBClicked = false
}

// method
fun myMethod() {
    // do work here

    if (buttonAClicked) {
        // button a has been clicked
    } else if (buttonBClicked) {
        // button b has been clicked
    } else {
        // no button clicked (assuming that you can't press two buttons at once)
    }
}
```

I think Android has other views (as someone said in the comments) that can achieve something similar to this without having to do all of this extra effort.